# Обернуть ссылку в html теги php

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обернуть ссылку в html тег.
Есть данный код, ко если `http` тогда не сработает.

```
$text = "text http://google.com text";
$text = preg_replace('(https://[\w+?\.\w+]+[a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\:\;\'\.\/]+[\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+)', "<a href='$0' target='_blank'>$0</a>", $text);
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Заэкранируйте два прямых слэша после указания протокола и сам протокол `https` лучше замените на группу `(http|https|ftp)`:

```perl
((http|https|ftp):\/\/[\w+?\.\w+]+[a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\:\;\'\.\/]+[\.]*[a-zA-Z0-9\/]+)
```

Comment: Для протоколов, можно использовать `h?t?f?tps?` за место группы и перечисления, да и вообще не асс регулярка... тяжелая и громоздкая. Может таких тормозов надавать, если адрес будет как у гугловских ссылок.